# Biological process in wastewater treatment

Tags: waste-water-treatment, waste-disposal

Biological process is the secondary stage in most of wastewater treatment plant. Is there any wastewater treatment plant without undergoing biological process?

Comment: I guess wastewater without any organic compounds like hydrocarbons or proteins can't be processed Biologically. This may be the case with some Sorte of industrial wastewater like solutions from galvanisation or steel works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure somewhere, someone is right now discharging a larger stream os wastewater with only a sieve or settlement tank as "treatment", so likely yes. Will this satisfy any sensible discharge limits? likely no. Can we assume you mean treated to sesnible sischarge limits? Can we assume domestic wastewater?

Comment: I am sure there are if "waste water" includes all types of industrial waste waters.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what is in the waste water, and how much is allowed to be left after treatment.

Treatment can mean anything from a settling tank, to a filter or screen, to oxygenating, to centrifuging, to active biological break down, and more.  In some cases, treatment means it flows thru a "magic pipe" and is simply discharged when no inspectors are looking.

Comment: i thought your answer was good.